# Android fullscreen image

Tags: android

I'm quite experienced Android developer but I have very easy problem.
How to properly make a fullscreen image in Android?
Currently I'm using one better quality image and use it on all devices. This works quite ok but downscalling on very small devices looks bad and it can cause an OOM Error.

There were few threads about it, for example:

- [fullscreen images and android resolutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160515/fullscreen-images-and-android-resolutions)
- [Full screen background image in an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135984/full-screen-background-image-in-an-activity)

But in my opinion answers are not right.
Everybody says that I should use ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi folders and I agree this works for small images (buttons, switches), nine patches, things that you want to have the same physical size on every screen.
When it comes to fullscreen this is wrong. My HTC Desire (480x800) is hdpi and my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (800x1280) is mdpi. Using above advices would result in Galaxy Tab 2 using smaller images than HTC Desire which is very wrong.

Is there any easy way to solve this fullscreen image problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the small-normal-large-xlarge qualifier. 
You can even mix multiple qualifier, for instance : drawable-small-hdpi or drawable-small-mdpi and have the right image.

Comment: I was actually thinking about it but that would mean I have to duplicate images. For example the same mid-res image would be in large-mdpi and normal-hdpi. This will cause APK to grow. This APK will be downloaded by some old, small HTC Wildfire with small free memory for apps. Does it mean I would also have to make different apks for different devices to make it perfect?

Comment: If you want it to be perfect, yes. But I hardly think that this is necessary. Take a look at this charts : http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens
You will see that large-mdpi is 2.9% of users whereas normal-hdpi is 37%, so avoid some size-density combination that are not common.

Comment: I was thinking more about a different apk for small/ldpi (10%) So that such small devices will not download and install not needed - hi-res images

Answer (score 1):

One option is to determine the screensize yourself ([Get screen dimensions in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions/1016941#1016941)) and then pick which image you use:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;

// Stuff
if      (width < /*some number*/)       putLowResFullScreenImage();
else if (width < /* a bigger number*/)  putMidResFullScreenImage();
else                                    putHighResFullScreenImage();
```

Comment: I knew I can make a code solution but this starts to be painful where there are more images like that :) But now when I think it seems that this could be better than normal-hdpi, large-mdpi folders because I wouldn't have to copy resources - there could be only few resources in no-dpi folder with different names.

Comment: I think that I read (but I can't find it again) that we can expect future android version to address this issue. If I find the link I'll add it to the answer.